# Can't setup site to be visible outside of Google cloud

Tags: windows, firewall

I have Google cloud virtual machine running Windows Server 2016. Run TensorBoard on it (Google executable, related to machine learning area) which create reports in the form of site, usually accessible through localhost:6006. I would like to look at this site from outside, by specifying VM’s external IP (like 35.185.x.x):6006. But this doesn't work. Although worked several months before. As I understand, I need to setup VM’s firewall, but everything seems to be already allowed:

[image]

What else to setup?

What else is strange is that I can't access the site at VM through localhost:6006 or 127.0.0.1. Only Machine-name:6006. I didn't see such things before, don't understand how this is possible. Ping Machine-name shows internal address 10.142.x.x. Ping from outside and remote desktop works through the external IP.

And another strange thing is very slow Remote desktop's files loading speed through \TSClient... About 1 file/second when loading folders contents and about 300 KB/s when copying one file. Google support said they don't impose any restrictions and refused to help with Microsoft products.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Checked local antivirus (Avira) and VPN. It looks like the problem is in both - without them it works.